# Adaptive cards in outlook not rendering for some users

Tags: json, outlook, power-automate, adaptive-cards

I have trouble getting adaptive card rendered for some users.
I'm sending out adaptive cards using Flow Automate. I've set up a provider in the actionable messages developer dashboard and added the originater id to the json request.

So in an example like:

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<script type="application/adaptivecard+json"> 
{
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
    "version": "1.0",
"hideOriginalBody": true,
    "originator": "xxx",
    "body": [
        {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "Do something",
            "wrap": true,
            "size": "Large",
            "weight": "Bolder"
        }
]
}
</script> 
</head>
<body>
Some body you shouldn't be able to see
</body>
</html>
```

For some users (in outlook webapp) this renders perfectly while for others it does not.

In addition I've installed the Actionable messages debugger for outlook which returns the following diagnostics when the message does not render:

```
{
"CardEnabledForMessage": false,
"ClientName": "OutlookWebApp",
"ClientVersion": "20210419002.02",
"InternetMessageId": "<DBAPR07MB6549BB8BCD3E00E240410D4683419@DBAPR07MB6549.eurprd07.prod.outlook.com>",
"EntityExtractionSuccess": false,
"Error": "EntityDocument does not exist.",
-"AdaptiveCardPayload": {
"found": true,
"type": "AdaptiveCard"
},
-"MessageCardPayload": {
"found": false,
"type": null
},
-"AuthHeader": {
"results": "gsv.dk; dkim=none (message not signed) header.d=none;gsv.dk; dmarc=none action=none header.from=GSVMaterieludlejning.onmicrosoft.com;",
"authAs": "Internal"
}
}
```